# Selecting Nodes using xPath with unions

Tags: xpath

I'm writing a basic HTML report templating system based on manipulating the data using xPath. Essentially, I need an xPath query which will select a node OR its children if they have a certain class.

```
$query = $xPath->query (".//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' -delete-if-no-stock ')]", $node);
```

I understand that the xPath selector `.//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' -delete-if-no-stock ')]` is specifically looking at *descendant nodes* of the `$node` parameter.

I would like an xPath query that essentially asks "the node or any of its children". I know that there is a union operator, `|`, but I haven't seen how to implement that. I would have imagined something like this: `.[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' -delete-if-no-stock ')] | .//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' -delete-if-no-stock ')]` but this generates an `Invalid expression` error.

Comment: By node OR its children you mean node AND its children?

Comment: I mean a logical OR, as in "Union".

Comment: Both parent and children should contain -delete-if-no-stock class?

Comment: @akond both parent and children class _could_ contain -delete-if-no-stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath expressions work as filters. They do not aggregate/compile in that kind of sense (Like an SQL Union).

Here are several possibilities depending on what you're trying to do.

## Alternative Expressions

The pipe symbol `|` allows you to specify multiple expressions - it works like the comma `,` in CSS selectors.

`expression_one|expression_two`

## Complex conditions

Conditions in the expressions can use `and` and `or` as well as brackets.

`/location/path[condition and condition or condition]`

## Axis

Xpath expressions have a concept of axis that define the initial set of nodes the filter is applied to.

`axis::node[condition]`

`.//*` is short for `self::node()/descendant::*`. Here is a axis called `descendant-or-self` that includes the current node and all descendants.

`descendant-or-self::*[contains(...)]`

Comment: Hi ThW,
Maybe you can help me. I found an expression like that `<xsl:template match="(rootelement1|rootelement)/some/path/etc" priority="1000" mode="M25">`
Is that valid? I can't find any documentation that allows you to use the brackets like that. I would be happy if you could give me some context.

Comment: Alternative expressions are only possible on the top level, they can not be parts of other expressions. You need to use conditions - for example `*[self::rootelement1 or self::rootelement2]/some/path/etc`.

Comment: Does it also work for XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @ThW could you point the source? I can't find such statement in the XPath 1.0 spec. This seems to be completely valid `filter_expr`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an axis operator...

```
descendant-or-self::node()[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' -delete-if-no-stock ')]
```