# XPath: get the element with same tag but different attribuite

Tags: xml, xpath

I've something like:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
    <d name='pa'/>
    <d name='pb'/>
   </c>
 </b>
</a>
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
    <d name='pc'/>
    <d name='pb'/>
   </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

with xpath how can I retrieve the element parent **a** which has both attribute `name=pa` and `name=pc` of tag **d**?

I tried with this one but it doesnt work:

```
(/a/b/c/d[@name='pa']) and (/a/b/c/d[@name='pc'])
```

but it just outputs `Boolean='true'`

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464046/selecting-nodes-using-xpath-with-unions/45470746#45470746

Comment: @MadManMoon, there is no such element on provided piece of `xml` source. Can you clarify which exact element you want to match?

Comment: @Andersson `<a>
 <b>
  <c>
    <d name='pa'/>
    <d name='pb'/>
   </c>
 </b>
</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
//a[.//d[@name="pa"] and .//d[@name="pb"]]
```

which should return your desired output

Comment: that works! thank you, I just figured out that I need a little update, what if I wanna get the elements with both attributes (**pa** and **pb**) but also elements with  just attribute **pa** or **pb**?

Comment: `//a[.//d[@name="pa" or @name="pb"]]` should return `a` element with child `d` which has  attribute `"pa"` or `"pb"`. If you want to get element that *has both* `"pa"` and `"pb"` *or contains only one `d`* that has `"pa"` or `"pb"` then `//a[.//d[@name="pa"] and .//d[@name="pb"]] | //a[.//d[@name="pa" or @name="pb"]and count(.//d)=1]` should work

Comment: thank you so much for your fast answer, you're really a life saviour, sorry to bother again but my scenario is a bit more complex. Suppose **d** tags are permissions and **a** tags actions. I’m looking for a query that lists available actions for a user having a list of permissions.

Comment: Can you update your ticket appropriately or open new ticket related to this issue? It'd be easier to solve your problem if I see the exact `xml` sample and desired output